# Build is fine but running command ./gradlew build fails

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, continuous-integration

My application is building ok but I'm trying to run some gradlew commands and it always fail.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.20' apply false
id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
id("com.google.firebase.appdistribution") version "4.0.0" apply false
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.21-1.0.11' apply false
```

}

```
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip

Kotlin:       1.8.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x2df5032d) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x2df5032d at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.(KaptContext.kt:55) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:35) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
```

> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
>   Caused by:
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException:
>   A failure occurred while executing
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:256)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
>   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:313)
>   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:259)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
>   at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
>   ... 2 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed
>   module @0x2df5032d) cannot access class
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because
>   module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to
>   unnamed module @0x2df5032d
>   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.(KaptContext.kt:55)
>   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:35)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
>   ... 31 more

Comment: You probably don't want to target JDK 17, see: https://developer.android.com/build/jdks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `jdk` version and make sure its 17 since you are using this version in your build files.

```
$ java --version

openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+8, mixed mode)
```

If not, install `jdk17` and try again. Higher versions like 19 or 21 can cause this issue.

Comment: It worked, thanks. My java version was 21, after uninstalling it and installing 17 it worked.

Comment: Glad to head that! @Johnny

Answer (score 0):

Building your application from IDE is just passing down the commands to gradle wrapper. Have you tried just running `./gradlew help` to see if the problem is still present?

If it does, one possible explanation is the mismatch between JDKs in your local environment and IDE. Your terminal (even the one inside IDE) is running Gradle against your `JAVA_HOME` JDK while it's possible your IDE relies on a JDK shipped inside of it. If you are on IntelliJ platform you can press `Command+Shift+A` and search for "Change Gradle JDK location" action. That way you will be able to verify if that's the root cause of your problem.

> Remember that it's important to have the same JDK for both terminal and IDE as it avoids creating a second Gradle daemon for another JDK. You can check your Gradle daemons via `./gradlew --status`. You can kill all daemon processes via `pkill -f '.*GradleDaemon.*'`

Consider using toolchain.

More info here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html